# What's the difference between Alarm Budget and CloudWatch alarms Billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to understand what is the difference between using **Budgets**(cost budget) and Configure **Billing Alerts** in AWS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Billing Alerts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#creating_billing_alarm_with_wizard) are very limited as compared to [Budgets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html). Most notably, the billing alarm represents only the amount you have been already charged. In contrast, a budget can alarm you based on **forecasted charges**, which can give you a bit of head up to figure out what's happening before you get hit with excess bill usage.

The other key difference is that Budgets allow you to create **filtered alarms**, only for some regions and services of interest. Filtering by region is not possible with billing alerts. Another thing is that budget support **linked accounts**, which again is not possible with the billing alerts.

Finally, budgets are far **easier** to use, set up and manage, than billing alerts.

Comment: How about fee both of them?

Comment: Budgets: first two free, with 10cents/alarm/day above the free tier [source](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-budgets/pricing/)
Billing alarms: 10 regular resolution free tier and additional cost above that [source for billing alarms](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, other power of the Budget as:

1. **Filter by multiple dimension**: Region, Service Type, Instance Type, AZ, Tag, linked account, etc...
   [image]
2. **Budget can *take action* (Ex: Stop EC2)**
   [image]

- Note: CloudWatch can take action if you trigger a lamda function.

3. **Notification preferences - Optional**

You can select 1 or more notification preferences to receive alerts: `Email, SNS Alert`.

[image]